# How to create a prometheus graph in grafana to get division of two queries?

Tags: java, spring-boot, grafana, prometheus

I have created two queries in Prometheus data source.

1. sum(increase(transaction_seconds_sum{action = 'initiate'}[1m]))
2. sum(increase(transaction_seconds_count{action = 'initiate'}[1m]))

Is there any way to divide the first query by the second one and generate one graph in a specific time interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to calculate the average? Then:

```
sum(increase(transaction_seconds_sum{action = 'initiate'}[1m])) / sum(increase(transaction_seconds_count{action = 'initiate'}[1m]))
```

See [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/) for the available operators.

Comment: Thanks @mweirauch, it worked for me also I tried getting sum after dividing both the queries and it worked what I want. something like below :

sum(increase(transaction_seconds_sum{action = 'initiate'}[1m]) / increase(transaction_seconds_count{action = 'initiate'}[1m]))

Comment: It is a solution, but not really a nice solution. In Grafana+graphite you can generate 2 queries (A & B), make these invisible and then create query C: #A / #B, what is much easier if the queries get complexer. Anyone knows if this is possible with Prometheus?

Comment: @Sven, Prometheus doesn't provide query templating. Take a look at [with templates in VictoriaMetrics](https://play.victoriametrics.com/promql/expand-with-exprs). It allows writing something like `WITH (A = ..., B = ...) A / B`